# Doubling/tripling puzzle: make 1 from 1536 in as few steps as possible

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

You start with the number 1536. Your mission is to get to 1 in as few steps as possible. At each step, you may either multiply or divide the number you have, by either 2 or 3; but, only if the result is a whole number whose first digit is 1, 3, 4, or 9. That is all.

Comment: "first digit" meaning the ones digit, or "first digit" meaning most significant digit?

Comment: @Hugh - most significant.

Comment: I wonder if the fact that the prime factorization of 1536 is $2^9 \times 3$. That puts a lower bound of at least 10 operations, but it must be more since just trying possibilities shows that there must be some multiplications in there.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As Jo has already shown, this can be accomplished in

> 28 steps. This is minimal, and it can be proven.

To help visualize this problem, we can imagine:

> A two-dimensional grid/chart where each point is a number of the form $3^x2^y$, with $(x,y)$ as the relevant co-ordinates. We want to find a path from $(1,9)$ to $(0,0)$ while making only one step up/down/left/right at a time, and ensuring that the numbers we step on have their most significant digit in the set {1,3,4,9}.
>  Here is what the chart looks like for the range $(0,0)$ to $(10,10)$. The dashes represent numbers that do not begin with {1,3,4,9}, and so are unusable in our path.
>  `1024  3072  9216  ----   ----   ----    ----    ----     ----     ----      ----     .`
>  `----  1536  4608  13824  41472  124416  373248  1119744  3359232  10077696  30233088 .`
>  `----  ----  ----  ----   ----   ----    186624  ----     1679616  ----      15116544 .`
>  `128   384   1152  3456   10368  31104   93312   ----     ----     ----      ----     .`
>  `----  192   ----  1728   ----   15552   46656   139968   419904   1259712   3779136  .`
>  `32    96    ----  ----   ----   ----    ----    ----     ----     ----      1889568  .`
>  `16    48    144   432    1296   3888    11664   34992    104976   314928    944784   .`
>  `----  ----  ----  ----   ----   1944    ----    17496    ----     157464    472392   .`
>  `4     12    36    108    324    972     ----    ----     ----     ----      ----     .`
>  `----  ----  18    ----   162    486     1458    4374     13122    39366     118098   .`
>  `1     3     9     ----   ----   ----    ----    ----     ----     19683     ----     .`
>  From here, we can see two different routes of 28 steps each: (1536->373248->93312->384->48->3888->972->36->9->1) and (1536->373248->46656->3779136->944784->3888->972->36->9->1).

Proving minimality:

> Since a path of length 28 exists (we've found two), we can rule out anything that's too far away to be used in a shortest path.
>  Moving from (1,9) to (0,0) must take at least ten steps on its own, so we can move at most nine steps completely out of the way (and nine steps back) in a shortest route. That limits us to only considering x-coordinates up to 10; any further would require making at least ten '*3' steps, eleven '÷3' steps, and at least nine '÷2' steps, putting the route definitely longer than 28.
>  With our x-coordinate limited to [0,10], we now look at the bottlenecks.
>  It should be clear that any shortest route must start by going from 1536 to 93312 in seven steps, and must end by going from 3888 to 1 in nine steps. These are both forced by unique bottlenecks; there is only one way to step from $(x,7)$ to $(x,6)$ and only one way to step from $(x,3)$ to $(x,2)$ in this range.
>  This leaves at most twelve steps to go from 93312 to 3888. Either by observation or by pointing out that there are only two ways to go from $(x,6)$ to $(x,5)$, we can see that there are exactly two shortest routes from 93312 to 3888, and both require all twelve steps.
>  Therefore, the shortest route is 28 steps, and there are exactly two ways to do so, both of which are described in Jo's solution and below the chart.

Comment: The grid was the intended answer, however @Jo.'s was the first correct, complete and minimal answer.

Comment: @deepthought: You don't have to give the accepted answer to the first answer given. This site is as much about (or moreso in my view) how to solve puzzles than just what the answer is. The other answer gives an answer but says nothing about how to solve the puzzle or even proving that it is the best answer. It is of course up to you to accept what you want but out of correct, complete and minimal I'd argue that the other answer isn't complete and that minimal is actually a point against it, not for it.

Comment: I agree that this deserves to be the accepted answer. Jo's answer does deserve an upvote as well for being first and correct though.

Comment: @Chris - I meant minimal, as in minimal distance through the maze. I did not specify 'prove it' or anything like that in the question. Thus I must consider the other answer complete. I am unwilling to change the question after the fact.

Comment: @deepthought: ah, yes, it is minimal in that regards. Personally I don't consider this site to be a race though. As with any stack site if an answer is better I think it deserves the tick more. Sure, if you are first it means you may well get it because other answers that don't add anything won't compete against you. But first does not make an answer better. Still, its your question so you get to decide what rules you use to choose the accepted answer.

Comment: @Chris - I don't know enough about other stacks, but perhaps one difference is that, around here, there is often an "intended answer". And too often OP moves the goalposts to suit that answer :-) There is a "meta" question here, which I may post .... but later.

Comment: Yeah. I quite agree that moving goalposts is bad but I don't think that's what I'm suggesting, I'm just suggesting an answer with workings is better than one without. I agree that it might be interesting meta conversation to be had to see if there is a consensus on things like whether questions should all be assumed to have implicit "And show your workings/thought process/etc." and so on. Though it may be there is already a meta question on this subject...

Comment: This grid explains why all solutions will have an even number of steps: just color the squares like a checkerboard.

Comment: @deepthought On Puzzling.SE multiple answers may arrive at the intended solution, but one may have a better explanation than the other. The asker can change their accepted answer if they prefer the other's explanation (often giving a bounty to the other answers). Ultimately it's the asker's decision.

Comment: @Chris - yeah meta already had some discussion. After poking around meta, and pondering the meaning of life, and such, I have reconsidered :-)

Answer (score 20):

Not sure if it is the quickest, but I found two ways to do it with 28 steps:

> ```
>    1536
> *3 4608
> *3 13824
> *3 41472
> *3 124416
> *3 373248
> /2 186624
> /2 93312
> /2 46656
> *3 139968
> *3 419904
> *3 1259712
> *3 3779136
> /2 1889568
> /2 944784
> /3 314928
> /3 104976
> /3 34992
> /3 11664
> /3 3888
> /2 1944
> /2 972
> /3 324
> /3 108
> /3 36
> /2 18
> /2 9
> /3 3
> /3 1
> ```

and

> ```
>    1536
> *3 4608
> *3 13824
> *3 41472
> *3 124416
> *3 373248
> /2 186624
> /2 93312
> /3 31104
> /3 10368
> /3 3456
> /3 1152
> /3 384
> /2 192
> /2 96
> /2 48
> *3 144
> *3 432
> *3 1296
> *3 3888
> /2 1944
> /2 972
> /3 324
> /3 108
> /3 36
> /2 18
> /2 9
> /3 3
> /3 1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is relevant to the topic, but I wrote a python program that recursively builds sequences for valid operations. I limited it to 32 steps, so it will output the 2 optimal 28-steps solutions and 26 more for 30 and 32 steps (there are no 29/31 steps solutions)

Operations: 0: *3, 1: *2, 2: /2, 3: /3

```
def get_next(sequence, prev_op):
    crt = sequence[-1]

    if crt == 1536:
        print((len(sequence) - 1), sequence)
        return

    if len(sequence) > 32: return

    if prev_op != 3 and str(crt * 3)[0] in '1349':
        get_next(sequence + [crt * 3], 0)
    if prev_op != 2 and str(crt * 2)[0] in '1349':
        get_next(sequence + [crt * 2], 1)
    if prev_op != 1 and crt % 2 == 0 and str(crt // 2)[0] in '1349':
        get_next(sequence + [crt // 2], 2)
    if prev_op != 0 and crt % 3 == 0 and str(crt // 3)[0] in '1349':
        get_next(sequence + [crt // 3], 3)

get_next([1], 2)
```

Comment: Python has a function called `divmod` which returns the result of dividing and modulus. `next, rem = divmod(crt, 2)` for instance. This would save you the doubled division.

Comment: It's obvious that there are no solutions with an odd number of steps.  The starting number has $10$ prime factors, the target has none, and you get one factor more or fewer at each step.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Python solution from user54653. I wrote this brute force solution before I looked at theirs. Runs under py2 or py3. This solution is a little more glitzy. I track the operations made as well as the numeric sequence.

> ```
> def find_sequence(target):
>     queue = [1]
>     seen = {1: [(1, '*1')]}  # prevent loops
>
>     while queue:
>         current = queue.pop(0)
>         steps = seen[current]
>
>         if current == target:
>             return steps
>
>         # notice the use of slice copying ([:]). Without this the same
>         # list would be reused in multiple places leading to incorrect
>         # results.
>
>         for i in (2, 3):
>             next, rem = divmod(current, i)
>             if rem == 0 and next not in seen:
>                 if str(next)[0] in ['1', '3', '4', '9']:
>                     queue.append(next)
>                     seen.setdefault(next, steps[:]).append((next, '/{}'.format(i)))
>         for i in (2, 3):
>             next = current * i
>             if next not in seen and str(next)[0] in ['1', '3', '4', '9']:
>                 queue.append(next)
>                 seen.setdefault(next, steps[:]).append((next, '*{}'.format(i)))
>
>     return None  # failed to compute a result.
>
>
> print(find_sequence(1536))
> ```

Comment: If anyone can offer a way to bury this in a spoiler tag I would love to hear it.